# SwiftUI view being rendered in small window instead of full-screen when using Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I recently created a new SwiftUI project using the beta for Xcode 12. Then I tried to open this project in the non-beta Xcode 11, and after updating the code to use a SwiftUI 1.0-style AppDelegate, I was able to build and run the app. The issue is that **now that I have moved to Xcode 11, the app renders inside of a small frame instead of taking up the whole screen.**

Here is a simplified example:

**Xcode 12 vs. Xcode 11**

[image: SwiftUI app taking up whole screen] [image: SwiftUI rendering in small frame, not full screen]

---

My simplified view's code is as follows:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World!")
        }
    }
}
```

AppDelegate:

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
}
```

SceneDelegate:

```swift
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

---

I have tried creating a new Xcode 11 project (which renders properly) and comparing its contents to my own project's, but so far I have not been able to find any difference between its AppDelegate, SceneDelegate, ContentView, build settings, etc.

**Is there an option that should be changed in order to have SwiftUI render full-screen in the Xcode 11 project?**

Comment: I'm getting this when running iPad in the Simulator. Can someone clarify, is this only an issue in the Simulator or does it also happen on real devices?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is caused because **the Xcode 11 project is missing a Launch Screen.**

This can be resolved by doing the following:

- Right click on your project's name, choose **New File…**, and select **Storyboard**.
- In the storyboard, add a new View Controller.
- In your app target's settings, find the **"App Icons and Launch Images"** section.
- Select your launch screen from the dropdown:

  [image]

Now run your application and the SwiftUI view will fill up the whole screen!

Comment: I just ran into this with Xcode 12.3. Very weird, and clearly a bug, but your solution worked.

Comment: Many thanks my dude, I don't know why this isn't the case by default!

Comment: If I type in a random string into the "Launch Screen File" field. It works! Any random gibberish like "osd8nfcosd" and it still works. Bizzare lol.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. XCode 12.5.1 still has this bug, whereas the XCode 13 beta does not.

Comment: Xcode 13.1 has this bug for me and this fixed it

Comment: I'm still getting this bug in 13.2.1. This workaround still works. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I just got bitten by this in Xcode 15. Like others, I was a little too thorough in my code tidying up. I added a LaunchScreen storyboard (actually resurrected it from my git repo) and all is good. Seems like a Pooh trap for Heffalumps, or a Heffalump traps for Poohs. I could try the random text string in the info plist, but I might just put some nice graphics in the launch screen

Answer (score 29):

Simply adding

```
<key>UILaunchScreen</key>
<dict/>
```

Into the info plist solved this for me.
[image]

Comment: Had to clean build after making this change. Works, thanks.

Comment: wow - worked for me to. I was too aggressive cleaning up the Info.plist after migrating to a full SwiftUI project. But why ????

Comment: The solution is working fine on SwiftUI project that migrated from UiKit, But I don't know what is the root cause.somebody help?

Comment: This is the fix. 
Btw, issue still happening with Xcode 14.3.1 in Simulators for iOS 16 and 17.

Comment: This works even for a pure SwiftUI project that builds for macOS and iOS. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this is to add a LaunchScreen entry in Info.plist as follows -

```html
    <key>UILaunchScreen</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIColorName</key>
        <string>LaunchBackground</string>
    </dict>
```

The LaunchBackground must correspond to a color in Assets.xcassets.

Answer (score 0):

[@ahimsa das](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9971602/ahimsa-das) mentioned that

> If I type in a random string into the "Launch Screen File" field. It works! Any random gibberish like "osd8nfcosd" and it still works. Bizzare lol.

which is weird but I think it has something to do with the cache on iOS. By typing a random string into the launchscreen file name (in the app's target settings), xcode searches your project for the storyboard file, but since it cant find any, it defaults to a cached image of the launchscreen (correct me if I'm wrong) which would be the image of the very first `launchscreen.storyboard` file that was created

(in my case this happened as I was using UIKit and wanted to make an app programmatically so I deleted `launchscreen.storyboard` and all references to it, which of course, resulted in a small `UIWindowScene`)

Answer (score -3):

Use `ignoresSafeArea`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World!")
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```