# How to conditionally load view upon app launch in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, userdefaults

I'm currently trying to implement an auto-login feature to my app using UserDefaults. What I would like to do before loading any view is get the UserDefaults email and password and call the login function from my API. If successful, go to Home view, else go to LoginView. My apologies, I'm very new to Swift and on a tight schedule with my project. Here is my code segment. I'm not sure where I can add my logic:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    init() {
        let email = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "email");
        let pw = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "pw");
        
        let api = MyAppAPI()
        api.signInUser(email: email, password: pw) { result in
            //JSON response contains an 'isError' field
            let isError = result.value(forKey: "error") as! Bool
            
            if !isError {
                //successful login - what to do from here?   
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            LoginView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would advise against holding up app launch until you've made a successful network call. I'd launch the user to a loading/transient screen of some sort and then navigate them to the appropriate screen after the network call has been parsed. If this is a banking app, for example, that requires network connectivity then this is definitely how I'd go. But if this is a social networking app, for example, then I would avoid this approach and try to make the UX as offline-capable as possible that works to some extent even without connection.

Comment: Requiring network connectivity will suffice. This is a semester-long project where I had to learn Swift, PHP and AWS. There's really no purpose in using this app offline. I suppose some info could be cached, but that's out of scope for this project and my experience level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way of doing this, you can do this **onAppear**

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let email: String
    let pass: String

    init() {
        self.email = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "email") ?? ""
        self.pass = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "pw") ?? ""
    }
    
    @State private var result: Bool?

    var body: some View {
        
        Group {
            
            if let unwrappedResult: Bool = result {
                
                if unwrappedResult {
                    
                    Text("Home View, Welcome!")
                }
                else {
                    
                    Text("Wrong User or Pass, try again!")
                }
                
            }
            else {
                
                Text("loading...")
                
            }
  
        }
        .onAppear() { loginFunction(email: email, pass: pass) { value in result = value } }

    }
}
```

---

```
func loginFunction(email: String, pass: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(3000)) { completion(Bool.random()) }
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I will give this approach a shot

Comment: Your example has worked excellent with the exception of 1 strange issue. My app currently has a launch screen. I removed it from Info.plist and placed the image in the last else block to serve as my new launch screen. Now whenever I launch the app the whole entire app window is super tiny, kind of like running an app on an iPad that only supports iPhone screens. If I keep the launch screen in Info.plist everything is perfect, but obviously there is no point of having a launch screen just to go to a view with the same image. Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: that sound deferent issue and deferent question, you can make a new question for that if you like, but for current question I think we are done here.

Comment: Figured it it out. For some reason that happens when there is not a launch screen, so I essentially just have a blank launch screen for a brief moment before going to this view (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63195985/swiftui-view-being-rendered-in-small-window-instead-of-full-screen-when-using-xc). Thank you for the incredibly useful ContentView example!

Comment: @nickconnors: just please do not mix your questions with new issue for getting new answers in your next questions, your original question was: **How to conditionally load view upon app launch in SwiftUI?** you did not mentioned about **launch screen**, also I did not even tried to answer about launch screen issue either! I know that your are new to SOF, but please just ask one question and stay on one question and do not change question by the time. ps: my answer was and is for your original question and I think it is a good example as an Answer.